# if/else strive for logical completeness in single return function

Tags: c, misra, cert

I'm attempting to exist at the crossroads of MISRA C and CERT C and setting the lofty goal of no exceptions.  The two rules most against my normal patterns are (paraphrased):

- MISRA : A function should only have one return
- CERT : Strive for logical completeness

The CERT rule keeps catching me when I have nothing to say in an else.  For example:

```
static int32_t SomeFunc()
{
    int32_t retval = PROJECT_ERROR_GENERIC;

    retval = ChildFuncOne();
    if (retval == PROJECT_SUCCESS)
    {
        retval = ChildFuncTwo();
    }

    //Common cleanup

    return retval;
}
```

Assuming there is no specific cleanup for the failure of ChildFuncOne, I have nothing to say in else.  Am I missing another way to lay out this function?

Comment: Seems to me that the CERT rule was intended for more complicated conditions, e.g. `if (a && !b) {} else if (!a && b) {}` where logical completeness requires two more conditions `else if (a && b) {} else if (!a && !b) {}`. But as you already mentioned, there may be nothing to say for a particular condition, and then you end up with an `else if` followed by an empty body.

Comment: Arguably, no code change is required to "*strive* for logical completeness".  Also, MSC01-C is a recommendation, not a rule (CERT distinguishes between these), so the code presented does not fail to conform to the CERT.  This kind of situation may even be among the reasons *why* it is a recommendation.

Comment: There are in fact at least three ways to restructure the code to avoid having an `if` without an `else`, all covered by various answers, but my personal recommendation for serving CERT's apparent purpose in this area is simply to add a code comment after the closing brace of the `if` body that clarifies the intent.  Maybe something like `// else no additional action`.  I tend to start such comments with the word "else" to emphasize that they appear instead of an `else` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem with your code I can find is the obsolescent style function definition. `static int32_t SomeFunc()` should be `static int32_t SomeFunc(void)`. The former has been obsolescent form in C since some 25-30 years back and also violates MISRA 8.2 for that reason. Other than that, the code is fine and MISRA compliant.

A style comment beyond MISRA is that I would use an `enum` over `int32_t`.

---

Regarding CERT I assume you refer to [MSC01-C](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/MSC01-C.+Strive+for+logical+completeness). This is a fuzzy and unclear rule, with just a bunch of non-related code examples. I would just ignore it.

The corresponding MISRA C:2012 15.7 and 16.1 are much clearer and can be summarized as:

- All `else if` should end with an `else`.
- All `switch` should contain `default`.

The rationale is defensive programming and self-documenting code: "yes, I have definitely considered this outcome". Likely this is what CERT C tried (and failed) to say as well. They refer to various "`else if` with `else`" rules in their crossref.

This isn't applicable to your code. Nobody requires that every `if` ends with an `else`, that would be a ridiculous requirement.

---

> Am I missing another way to lay out this function?

It's sound practice to set the result variable to a known default state at the beginning of a function and later overwrite it if needed. So your function is not only compliant, but also fairly canonical style as safety-related programming goes.

So other than the `()` to `(void)`, there's no need to change a thing.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Well to begin with, it's pretty questionable to have a chapter named "miscellaneous" in a professional coding standard. It's not far from "random stuff".

Answer (score 3):

Option 1 is an `else` with an empty body:

```
static int32_t SomeFunc(void)
{
    int32_t retval = PROJECT_ERROR_GENERIC;

    retval = ChildFuncOne();
    if (retval == PROJECT_SUCCESS)
    {
        retval = ChildFuncTwo();
    }
    else
    {
        // yes, I did consider every possible retval
    }

    //Common cleanup

    return retval;
}
```

Option 2 is to add a second variable, and then set that variable in the `if` and the `else`. Note that I reversed the sense of the `if`, since that order makes more sense to me. YMMV.

```
static int32_t SomeFunc2(void)
{
    int32_t retval = PROJECT_ERROR_GENERIC;
    int32_t finalretval = PROJECT_ERROR_GENERIC;

    retval = ChildFuncOne();
    if (retval != PROJECT_SUCCESS)
    {
        finalretval = retval;
    }
    else
    {
        finalretval = ChildFuncTwo();
    }

    //Common cleanup

    return finalretval;
}
```

The problem with option 2 is that it's easy to mix up the two variables that have similar names and uses. Which is where these coding standards make your code more likely to have bugs, rather than less.

Comment: This is much worse and not required. Lesson #1 in engineering: question the requirements.

Comment: Option 3: use the ternary operator to conditionally update `retval` to the result of `ChildFunctTwo()`.  Not that I would recommend this over option 1 in practice.

Comment: If I could give two checks I would.  I like option one to shut up a picky static analysis tool, if pressed to do so.  But I think Lundin is correct in their interpretation of the rules and the code is more legible without the empty else.

Answer (score 1):

My attempt:

```
static int32_t SomeFunc()
{
    int32_t retval = ChildFuncOne();
    retval = (retval == PROJECT_SUCCESS)? ChildFuncTwo()   : retval;
    retval = (retval == PROJECT_SUCCESS)? ChildFuncThree() : retval;

    return retval;
}
```

Basically, the `retval` is set by the first function, and ***only*** if that result is `PROJECT_SUCCESS`, will the second function get called and set the `retval`.

If the `retval` is anything other than success, it remains unchanged, the second function is never called, and `retval` is returned.

I even show how it can be chained for an arbitrary number of functions.

I'm a bit unclear what you mean bye "common cleanup", so if you need different cleanup operations depending on what functions succeeded and failed, that will take extra work.

Comment: This is much worse and not required. Lesson #1 in engineering: question the requirements. Also, MISRA frowns upon having side effects inside `?:`. And you would need even more parenthesis to make operator precedence explicit. The OPs code is superior to this.

Answer (score -1):

You should stop trying to appease the MISRA and CERT gods and just write clear code.  The code that you posted is fine.  Keep it that way.

Comment: I find it useful to periodically review my coding patterns and style.  MISRA/CERT were not written in a vacuum.  Their effectiveness toward their goals can be debated but they are well meaning.  I am attempting to live by every rule to see if any useful patterns towards correctness emerge.  Not just to "appease" a standard.

Comment: There is no MISRA rule requiring any changes of this code either. It's easy to whine about MISRA when one doesn't even have a clue about the actual requirements.

Comment: This advice may be sound, but it is not responsive to the question posed, which is "Am I missing another way to lay out this function?"  It would be appropriate for a comment, but it does not answer the question.